# Is it possible that WP7.x APP can use full space on 16:9 (720P)device

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have application Using WP7.x SDK. I am not using any Window Phone 8 feature.
My App's XAML Pages are fitting perfectly on WVGA and WXGA but on 720P on top of screen there is some blank space. How can i fix this problem (I don't want to create seprate build for Window Phone 8).Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. The WP7 apps running on WP8 devices are constrained in a 480x800 container.

To take advantage of the 720p screen, you'll have to build a WP8 version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

At least graphically this is possible. You can handle WP7 XNA inputs and graphics right: look my awnswer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23457119/766304

Second thing that you have to do is render your Silverlight / XAML UI with XNA. More information about that from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221583.aspx

All of that is tested and works well but this will manipulate only rendering and not XAML input side, input fixing could be possible or not. Still difrense between those two aspect ratios is so small that result can be good enought.